# Grafana - World Map Plugin

Tags: grafana, world-map

I am trying connect two geographical Locations on the Grafana World Map Plugin, using a line, can anyone please tell me what's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

That's not currently possible in the World Map plugin. There is another plugin that does something with lines. Here is the [feature request issue on GitHub for this feature](https://github.com/grafana/worldmap-panel/issues/38#issuecomment-271174745) and the [other plugin](https://github.com/tkurki/grafana-track-map) is here.

Comment: Its actually quite possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468905/draw-lines-between-markers-in-leaflet

Comment: What do you mean by possible? You cannot currently draw lines between points with the Worldmap plugin. It is of course possible to change the plugin so that it supports that. Worldmap uses the Leaflet library as does the other plugin that I linked to. But I don't think I will be updating the Worldmap plugin to draw lines in the coming months.

Comment: In the WorldMap Plugin Leaflet Library there is a function called polyline which i used to connect 2 geographical locations using a line.

Comment: Do you mean that you forked the project and implemented it yourself and thereby making a new plugin - which is great. You can submit it to be published on grafana.com or if it is a general enough feature send a PR to the worldmap plugin repo on GitHub.

Comment: The polyline function is present in the leaflet library.

Comment: Think we're talking past each other. I meant that it was not possible currently without changing the code to do this in the Worldmap plugin. And then linked to the issue which discussed implementing it in Worldmap and then linked to another project where they had used Leaflet to draw lines. The Worldmap plugin and Leaflet are not the same project. It sounds like you cloned Worldmap on GitHub and implemented the feature yourself? If that's the case, maybe you would consider contributing it back by sending a Pull Request?