# Add markers and polylines to a Leaflet map from destinations in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, leaflet

I'm trying to create a Leaflet map, that automatically adds markers and polylines between destinations from a Google sheet.

I've managed to set up a map from other examples which is linked to my Google Sheet. You see the example here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tabletop@1.5.2/src/tabletop.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
      #map-div {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map-div"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

```
var map = L.map('map-div').setView([60.1682653, 24.9422078], 5);
var basemap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Basemap (c) <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  minZoom: 5,
  maxZoom: 100
});
basemap.addTo(map);

function addPoints(data, tabletop) {
  for (var row in data) {
    var marker = L.marker([
      data[row].Latitude,
      data[row].Longitude
    ]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup('<strong>' + data[row].Info + '</strong>');
  }
}

function init() {
  Tabletop.init({
    key: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rs6xPlJ8pU4UFfmokjATaf4dArMWxQxZcyS-xRIIFuY/edit?usp=sharing',
    callback: addPoints,
    simpleSheet: true
  })
}
init()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Enounce/kwvn5e6z/12/

But unfortunately, I don't have the skills to make the map do what I want:

- Draw lines between markers [Draw lines between markers in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468905/draw-lines-between-markers-in-leaflet)
- Zoom to fit all markers [Zoom to Fit All Markers on LeafletJS Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155534/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-leafletjs-map)
- If possible, add an overview of all destinations, much like the directions panel in Google Maps. I haven't been able to find examples of this though.

I'm unsure if this is at all possible with the destinations being in an external source. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Draw Line between markers:

You need to create a `L.Polyline` and add the latlngs to it:

```
function addPoints(data, tabletop) {
    var line = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);
    for (var row in data) {
    var marker = L.marker([
      data[row].Latitude,
      data[row].Longitude
    ]).addTo(map);
    line.addLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
    marker.bindPopup('<strong>' + data[row].Info + '</strong>');
  }
}
```

#### Zoom to fit all markers:

Add the markers to a `L.FeatureGroup()` and then you can fit the map bounds to the group bounds with `map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds());`

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

function addPoints(data, tabletop) {
    var line = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);
    for (var row in data) {
    var marker = L.marker([
      data[row].Latitude,
      data[row].Longitude
    ]).addTo(fg);
    line.addLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
    marker.bindPopup('<strong>' + data[row].Info + '</strong>');
  }
  
  map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds());
}
```

**BUT** you need to remove `minZoom: 5` from the TileLayer.

#### Destinations

Store the destinations in an array and then create a html element in the loop and add a click listener:

```
var destinationHTML = document.getElementById("destinations-body");

var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var destinations = [];
function addPoints(data, tabletop) {
    var line = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);
    for (var row in data) {
    var marker = L.marker([
      data[row].Latitude,
      data[row].Longitude
    ]).addTo(fg);
    line.addLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
    marker.bindPopup('<strong>' + data[row].Info + '</strong>');
    destinations.push({
        marker,
      data: data[row],
      id: row
    });
    
    
  destinationHTML.innerHTML += "<div class='destination-elm' onclick='destinationClick(\""+row+"\")'><span>"+data[row].Info+"</span></div>"
  }
  
  map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds());
}

function destinationClick(id){
    console.log(id)
  destinations.forEach(function(obj){
    if(obj.id == id){
        map.panTo(obj.marker.getLatLng());
    }
  })
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/k3b4nups/

Comment: Thanks, Falke-Design. That was everything I could ever ask for! How would the code look if I wanted a version without the destinations overview? I tried deleting parts in the HTML, but that took out most markers altogether.

Comment: Look into: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/Lh2p61jy/ Please don't forgett to accept the answer as correct